# my quokka vs code extension is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, vscode-extensions, quokka.js

it shows the following in the output :

> ​​​​​Quokka 'js.js' (node: v13.14.0, plugins: jsdom-quokka-plugin)​​​​
>   Unexpected token '?'    ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​Object.compileFunction​​​
> ​vm.js:344​

I was trying to run the extension and to get the desired output by running the extension.